# How to parse value to a specific div when pressing a button in Django

Tags: django, html

I have the following buttons that are made using Semantic UI:

```
<div class="ui animated fade button" onclick="showDiv()">
   <div class="visible content">{{ four }}</div>
   <div class="hidden content">Donate !</div>
</div>
<div class="ui animated fade button" onclick="showDiv()">
   <div class="visible content">{{ eight }}</div>
   <div class="hidden content">Donate !</div>
</div>
```

Those variables are being initialized like this:

```
{% with four="4 Euro" eight="8 Euro" %}{% endwith %}
```

I also have a `div` which appears anytime I press on a button, using the following function in JS:

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

and is looking like this:

```
<div id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;text-align: center;" class="answer_list" > You have just selected an amount of: {{ value depending on which button I pressed }} </div>
```

My question: How can I parse to `{{value depending on which button I pressed}}` the value of a pressed button ? So when I press the first button to have this message displayed:

> You have just selected an amount of: **4 Euro**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="ui animated fade button" onclick="showDiv('{{ four }}')">
   <div class="visible content">{{ four }}</div>
   <div class="hidden content">Donate !</div>
</div>
<div class="ui animated fade button" onclick="showDiv('{{ eight }}')">
   <div class="visible content">{{ eight }}</div>
   <div class="hidden content">Donate !</div>
</div>
```

and the banner:

```
<div id="welcomeDiv" style="..."></div>
```

and the JS:

```
function showDiv(str) {
    var div = document.getElementById('welcomeDiv');
    div.innerHTML = "You have just selected an amount of:" + str;
    div.style.display = "block";
}
```

Although there are probably better ways of doing this if you use jQuery. You should try to avoid inline `style=""` on your elements. You could also move "4 Euro", "8 Euro" into a list in your view and simply render the buttons using a loop.

I would do something like the following (with jQuery):

```
donation_values = [(4, "4 Euro"), (8, "8 Euro")]

...

{% for val, str in donation_values %}
    <div class="... button" data-value="{{ val }}>
        {{ str }}
    <div>
{% endfor %}

...

$(".btn").click(function(){
    $(".banner").text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Timmy. I'll try the second method ( using views ).